# Templating config file with docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

We have been using **ansible** to set up application, but now we're moving to **docker**, so I have a question about generating `sphinx.conf` (or any text file) from template.

I have template like this for **jinja2** (which is supported in **ansible**):

```
{% for locale in locales %}
answers_{{ locale }}
{% endfor %}
```

And `locales` var which is defined by `locales: {"ru", "en", "de"}`

So as a result i have:

```
answers_ru
answers_en
answers_de
```

Now is the question: what is the best way to do it using **docker**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a solution using simple bash script, so I didn't even alter the template.

```
#!/bin/sh

cat > /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf

for LOCALE in ru en de ;
do
    sed "s/{{ locale }}/${LOCALE}/g" ./template/index.conf.template >> /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You most probably want to generate / configure some templates during startup / runtime ( container ) not during build, since e.g. your amount of installation / site name and vhost will only differ and you would need to build a new image for every different site on the same stack.

You might want to have a look at [tiller](https://github.com/markround/tiller) which is a template-system for docker supporting different value backends like files ( yml ), environments, defaults and then more complex KV pairs like consul/etcd.

This is much more the way you want to go coming from ansible, we did the same when coming from Chef.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ansible!

Deploy the config file into your Docker build dir along with a `Dockerfile` and [build the image](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_image_module.html).

```
- template: |
    src=sphinx.j2
    dest=./myimage/sphinx.conf
    owner=bin
    group=wheel
    mode="u=rw,g=r,o=r"

- name: Build an image and tag it
  docker_image:
    path: ./myimage
    name: myimage
    tag: latest
```

Ansible managed Dockerfiles can be handy too.

Comment: The original poster was moving away from Ansible! oh - maybe thats what you meant - use Ansible in a different way in the new context. wasn't obvious on first read

Comment: Yes, docker in many ways is a step backwards from config management back to hacky shell scripts to do similar tasks. The two aren't mutually exclusive though and OP didn't seem to be moving away from ansible, just towards docker.